# Store and retrieve data for API calls

Tags: ios, swift, database, rest, struct

I'm developing shop app and I have option where user can select multiple items(clothes) with different sizes quantities.

For this I have created struct, so final result of items in cart looks like:

```
let products = [
    Product(id: "1", quantities: [("1", 10), ("2", 10)]),
    Product(id: "2", quantities: [("1", 10), ("2", 10)]),
    Product(id: "3", quantities: [("1", 15), ("2", 20)]),
    Product(id: "4", quantity: 10),
]
```

My problem is that I'm creating this array inside one class and then should send it to server in another class. Main point is that user can continue using app so my product data should be always somewhere stored and updated if he adds new products.

What is the best way to store and retrieve the data of this array inside my class that handles calls to api after user finished creating his order?

Should store it UserDefaults, Realm, or declare global variable?

I know this might be rather simple question and there are other similar questions on SO, but since there are many ways of achieving this task, I would like to know which one is the best and "Swifty" in my particular case. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it all depends on your requirements. If you don't care about the user progress, e.g user quits the app and open the app again, they will lose their progress and will have to start over, then go with the `singleton`. Create a singleton class and save your array there.
If you want to save the user progress, so if they quit the app and open again, they can start right where they left. Then go with the `UserDefault`.
Now if you have a simple and small dataset then use `UserDefaults`, and if it's a complex and large dataset, then use `CoreData`, `Realm` or any other database you like.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I went with creating `singleton`